# search string from another string and add these string to array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, function, output

My string is:

```
$str = "a quick brown fox over the lazy dog... #fox #dog. hello everybody #lazy";
```

I want to get `#fox, #dog` and `#lazy` from that string and also every words that contains`#` and I want to add these string to an array like that:

```
 $array = array(
       [0]=>'#fox',
       [1]=>'#dog',
       [2]=>'#lazy',
   );
```

Anyone who can help me.. Please. Thanks a lot!

Comment: StackOverflow for this? O tempora..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of this regular expression `'/#(\w+)/'`

```
<?php
$str = "a quick brown fox over the lazy dog... #fox #dog. hello everybody #lazy";
preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/', $str, $matches);
array_walk($matches[1],function (&$v){ $v='#'.$v;});
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => #fox
    [1] => #dog
    [2] => #lazy
)
```

[image]

Comment: "*and also every words that contains #*"- It's unclear if OP wants to match `foo#bar` or not.

Comment: I've got it. Thank you so much! Your code is really cool.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
$s = "a quick brown fox over the lazy dog... #fox #dog. hello everybody #lazy";
$r = array();
preg_match_all('/(?<!\w)#\w+/', $s,$r);
print_r($r);
```

Answer (score 0):

using the regex whith `preg_match_all` you get a single array with all words starting with `#` contained in the string.

```
$str  = "a quick brown fox over the lazy dog... #fox #dog. hello everybody #lazy";
$pattern = '/(?<!\w)#\w+/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str , $matches);
print_r($matches);
```